# HTML simple not blank pattern

Tags: regex, html

I have a simple form and i want the submit button not to work for the conditions i give in the pattern, but if i leave it blank the submit works. how can i make the pattern not to accept it if it is blank?

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
Enter user name: 
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I thought the {1,20} is enought but it seems it's not.

Comment: You could use javascript to check if there is anything in the input box then signal the submit button to be disabled or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766015/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-required-field-to-ignore-white-space

Answer (score 95, accepted):

HTML has the `required` attribute to accomplish this. If you set any input to be required, modern browsers won't let you submit the form if those fields are empty.

```
<input type="text" name="username" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}">
```

Comment: The "required" attribute is boolean, so you can simply write "required", with no value.

Comment: Be aware that 'required' still allows the user to enter an empty string (ie. one or more spaces). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766015/is-it-possible-to-configure-a-required-field-to-ignore-white-space?lq=1

Comment: This is showing error onpage load as well. I want something which doesn't show error on page load but only on submit

Comment: worked perfectly but is there a possibility of doing through the html pattern itself?? @feeela

Comment: @pavankumar Doing what through the `pattern` attribute?

Comment: @feeela obviously to give a pattern that checks empty string.i don't want to use neither required attribute nor some javascript code

Comment: `a b` is invalid, any trick to make this valid? like `trim()` in JS?

Comment: @feeela you can use PHP ValueObject to check whether an empty string has been passed. Just implement __toString() to use the ValueObject directly like a string variable later, and check in constructor if " " was passed

Comment: @clockw0rk If at some point a combination of `trim` and `empty` is not sufficient anymore, I might do so…

Answer (score 3):

To prevent errors from showing on load, you can not use the HTML5 required attribute. You can use JavaScript. For example:

```
if ( $('#form-password').val() === "" ) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Using HTML Patterns to match at least one:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern=".{1,}">
```