# Is it possible to configure a required field to ignore white space?

Tags: html, required-field

The [required](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-required-attribute) attribute in HTML5 is very handy:

```html
<input type="text" required>
```

But it still allows users to enter white space only.
Is there an HTML-only solution to this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use the `pattern` attribute combined with the `required` attribute.  And be sure to include a `title` attribute as well, since most browsers insert the title text into the validation pop-up bubble.

```
<input required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="This field is required">
```

The `.*\S+.*` pattern requires at least one non-whitespace character, but also allows whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, carriage returns, etc.) at the beginning or end. If you don't want the user to be able to put whitespace at the beginning/end, then use this instead:

```
<input required pattern="\S(.*\S)?" title="This field is required">
```

Comment: _If you don't want the user to be able to put whitespace at the beginning/end, then use this instead_

No, it disallowes all of the whitecharacters. Required parrern is `"\S.*\S"`.

Comment: @KonstantinNikitin: ..and that in turn requires at least two characters.  If a single non-whitespace character is also valid, you'll want `"\S(.*\S)?"`.

Answer (score 14):

Try the [`pattern` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute).  You'll need [a regex which specifies 'at least one character'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051989/8655).

Comment: You probably want `\S` to disallow all whitespace

Answer (score 4):

You probably want this:

```
<input type="text" required pattern="\S(.*\S)?">
```

(At least one non-whitespace character and no whitespace at the beginning or end of the input)

---

Or if whitespace at the beginning and end are fine, then this:

```
<input type="text" required pattern=".*\S.*">
```

Answer (score 0):

### step 1

create a Javascript function:

```
function ignoreSpaces(event) {
  var character = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    if (character == 32) return false;
}
```

### Step 2

use it on any text-input field in HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" onkeypress="return ignoreSpaces(event)">
```

### Working example :

index.html

```html
<html> 
<body>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="return ignoreSpaces(event)">
  
  <script>
    function ignoreSpaces(event) {
        var character = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
        if (character == 32) return false;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i can paste space